# Issue with formatting time duaration

Tags: java

Running the following code:

```
private static String formatDuration(final long duration) {
    final long hh = duration / 1000 / 3600;
    final long mm = duration / 1000 % 3600 / 60;
    final long ss = duration / 1000 % 3600 % 60;
    return hh + "h" + ":" + mm + "m" + ":" + ss + "s";
}


private static void printDuartion() throws ParseException{
    SimpleDateFormat PARSE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    long dayFrom = PARSE_FORMAT.parse("11/02/2014 00:00:00").getTime();
    long dayTo = PARSE_FORMAT.parse("11/03/2014 23:59:59").getTime();
    System.out.println(formatDuration(dayTo-dayFrom));
}
```

I have the an output:
48h:59m:59s

But actually it should be:
47h:59m:59s

Please help me find out where the mistake is.

Comment: no mistake getting `47h:59m:59s`

Comment: Mm and ss have identical expressions.

Comment: My output is 48h:59m:59s

Comment: I get the correct output `47h:59m:59s`. So there is no problem with your code.

Comment: perhaps you are executing a previously compiled file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct, I also get `47h:59m:59s`. Demo: http://ideone.com/fxZKba

I can only imagine that you are in a time zone where these days are affected by [Daylight saving time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). Like "Atlantic/Bermuda" in the following example:

```
   private static void printDuration() throws Exception {
      SimpleDateFormat PARSE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
      PARSE_FORMAT.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Atlantic/Bermuda"));
      long dayFrom = PARSE_FORMAT.parse("11/02/2014 00:00:00").getTime();
      long dayTo = PARSE_FORMAT.parse("11/03/2014 23:59:59").getTime();
      System.out.println(formatDuration(dayTo - dayFrom));
   }
```

In this case I get `48h:59m:59s` Demo: http://ideone.com/jQ7sX2

Comment: Thank you Tobías. My timezone is America/Los_Angeles.

Comment: In Los Angeles DST ends November 2, 2014. Therefore difference between these dates is 48h:59m:59s. You're welcome!